# Can you export a configurable product .csv and reuse it? Not working for me

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, export, superattribute

Another attempt to solve this, but it did not work.

**Is it possible, or not, to export a configurable product .csv and reuse it?**

I downloaded a different configurable product that had the exact same info except for a slight sku # change and one word is different in the product title, description, etc. I replaced everything necessary and triple-checked my work.

It still gives the same error.

**I have hundreds of each type of configurable product and want to use spreadsheets instead of doing this one at a time.** Thanks in advance.

Using Magento (version 1.9) System - Import.

I created a configurable product of four sizes using my attribute set (chains)and downloaded it to use as a template.

**I replaced one section at a time and checked the data with magento import.**

**The .csv was accepted until I replaced the super products sku's. I have no changes to the super products such as prices, etc.**

When I check data, I get:

**Product with specified super products SKU not found: : 1, 2, 3, 4**

Comment: Does anyone have an idea of how to create a .cvs for configurable products? I'm still hoping for a reply. This is for a clothing shop.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever been able to import products with SKUs like the ones you use? Generally, SKUs don't have spaces or special characters. I'm not sure, but the quote for inches may also be throwing you for a loop, as well.

SKUs are usually the actual part number by which you purchase or store your products. I would not think box18-16" (2.5mm) makes for a great SKU. Other systems that might use your SKU (e.g. fulfillment, etc.) will probably have problems with this format, as well.

To test, I would suggest you try using box18-16-2-5, box18-18-2-5, etc. as SKUs and see if those import better.

Comment: the sku is box18. I'm using a configurable attribute that includes size. I did it manually and downloaded that and that is how magento exported it.